Progress Bar : How to NOT show the Import settings pop-up when replacing the source of a data table?
I have a IronPython script where I am replacing the source of a Data Table.
Here an extract of my code :
def execute():
    memstream = MemoryStream()
    memwriter = StreamWriter(memstream)

    result_table = []
    result_table.append(''.join(map(compare_common_test,common)))

    memwriter.Write('\n'.join(result_table))
    memwriter.Flush()
    memstream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)

    readerSettings = TextDataReaderSettings()
    readerSettings.Separator = '\t'
    readerSettings.AddColumnNameRow(0)

    textDataSource = TextFileDataSource(memstream, readerSettings)

    results = Document.Data.Tables["Results"]
    Document.Data.Tables["Results"].ReplaceData(textDataSource)

ps = Application.GetService[ProgressService]()
ps.ExecuteWithProgress("Progress", "Progress", execute)

When I add a Progression bar for this function, the pop-up for the Import Settings of the data table is shown.
If I don't use the Progression Bar, I don't have this pop-up, which is what I need.
Do you know how I can remove this pop-up ?
